# Setup of wxwidget in Codeblock, ubuntu

Tags: c++, user-interface, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am trying to use wxwidgets in codeblock for C++ GUI.

I have the wxwidget 2.8 installed and codeblock works fine on complying normal cmd program.

When I build new projects using the wizard and run it, no error is find but also nth pop up.

On the build log

```
Checking for existence: /.../Debug/TheQuietListener
Executing: /.../Debug/TheQuietListener  (in /.../TheQuietListener/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

I tried another sample code online
[link](https://code.google.com/p/wxcalculator/downloads/detail?name=minesweeping.zip&can=2&q=)

And this give the error msg in bulid log

```
"minesweeping - Debug": The compiler's setup is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
Goto "Settings->Compiler and debugger...->Global compiler settings->unknown->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.
Skipping...
```

Not sure if it is correct but I have tried in Settings>Global Variables
Add in the field of base /usr/include/wx
but it is not helping

May I know if there are another setting that I need to do?
It will be great if website or book can be recommended for the use of wxwidget.

Many thanks!